# Why does the visual studio code C/C++ extension install the mono framework assemblies along with it?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, mono

I recently noticed, by installing VS Code on my fresh Debian install, that the VS Code extension installs the "Mono framework assemblies" along with it.

Why are those needed if Mono is a replacement for .NET (meaning C#, VBA...) and the extension is for C/C++ (and also, VS Code is an electron app)?

Comment: I think only the [extension devs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues) can answer that. Probably the extension being from msft, they re-use the [debugger core](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Architecture-of-the-MIEngine) from MSVC, which is made in C#.

Comment: you can look in the extension package.json if it depends on other extensions

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source code, the Mono dependency is required by the debugger adapter,

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Extension/tools/copyDebuggerDependencies.ts

```
function copyMonoDependencies(): void {
    const monoDeps: string = getRoot("monoDeps");

    copy(monoDeps, DebugAdapterPath, "OpenDebugAD7");
}
```

Comment: So basically do I have Mono installed on my machine now? Can I use the same installation for C# development?

Comment: If you want to do some C# development, you can. However, most .NET related guys go to .NET Core, not Mono now.